# Validate form with PHP + does not refresh if error is present

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to validate my form with php upon pressing submit and I want the following :

User press submit, if no errors are found, the registration form is processed and data is sent to database.

If errors are present, the page doesn't refresh and the error console appears.

Every time the user clicks submit, if errors are found the old messages are deleted & new messages posted in the error console div.

I wrote all the code for the form , validation(php) , Error console div & CSS . I just have no idea how to integrate them together

**something like:**

```
if ( ($username && $email) != 0 ) { error console + remain on same page } else {send to db};
```

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [1.ii.gl](http://1.ii.gl/5lasBG.png))</sub>

**PHP VALIDATION CODE**

```
        $username = 0;

        $uservar = $_POST['username'];

        if (empty($uservar))
    {
        $username = 1;
    } 
else if (!preg_match("/^\w{5,20}$/",$uservar))
    {   
        $username = 2;
    }


    if ( ($username) != 0 ) {

    echo "<h4 class='error2'><img src='http://s28.postimg.org/ql0x06555/warning6.png' alt='Error'>  Error Console</h4> </br>";


switch ($username) {

    case 1:
        echo "<img src='http://s27.postimg.org/vjxntq073/sign5.png' alt='Error'>";
        echo "     The Field 'Username' cannot be left blank";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "<img src='http://s27.postimg.org/vjxntq073/sign5.png' alt='Error'>";
        echo "     Invalid 'Username' Format - Please use Letters & Numbers only (5-20 Characters)";
        break;      
}}

</div>
```

**FORM:**

```
<form id="registration-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">


<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">

<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button-submit">Submit</button>


</form>
```

Comment: So what is the current behavior of your code?

Comment: I wrote all the code for the form , validation(php) , Error console div & CSS . I just have no idea how to integrate them together

Comment: Okay, so you need to put your php code within a proper php tag. Then on the action of your form, you need to call your php file. Currently you are just echoing something action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"

Comment: Don't give your submit button a name of *submit*. It will mask the form's submit method so `form.submit()` will try to call the control, not the method.

Comment: You can't perform form validation using php without sending a request to the server.  If you want the page to not refresh, you will need to perform the validation in javascript before the form is submitted.

Comment: @John_Nil "If errors are present, the page doesn't refresh and the error console appears." PHP behavior always refresh the page, you need to use javascript which does validation of your form then you post request to apache server

Comment: I already have JQuery validation actually , that's just a fail safe for those that don't have javascript enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. split your main php from your html
2. php in your html only handle simple logical and display result

As a quick answer, please check code below:

```
<?php

function valiation(){
    $aryMsg = array();
    $aryExport = array();
    if( !isset( $_POST['_submit'] ) ){
        //no submit
        return array( $aryMsg, $aryExport );
    }

    $aryPostFieldWhiteList = array( 'username' );
    //1. post content filter
    //make sure pass all the field you need from $_POST to $aryExport
    foreach( $aryPostFieldWhiteList as $strField ){
        $aryExport[$strField] = htmlentities( $_POST[$strField], ENT_QUOTES );
    }

    //2. post content filter
    //...
    //if username is wrong fill $aryMsg['username'] ... etc

    //3. check validation result
    if( sizeof($aryMsg) ){
        //means not pass the validation, return error message and filtered data
        return array( $aryMsg, $aryExport );
    }

    //4. past validation

    //4.1 all db, to insert result
    //db insert ...etc


    //4.2 page redirect to thank you page
    header( 'Location: /thankyou.php' );

    die();
}

list( $aryMsg, $aryPost ) = valiation();
?>
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php if( is_array( $aryMsg ) && sizeof( $aryMsg ) ):?>
        <h4 class='error2'><img src='http://s28.postimg.org/ql0x06555/warning6.png' alt='Error'>  Error Console</h4>
        <ul class="error_msg">
        <?php foreach( $aryMsg as $strMsg ):?>
            <li><?php echo $strMsg;?></li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif;?>

    <form id="registration-form" action="" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $aryPost['username'];?>">

        <button type="submit" name="_submit" id="submit" class="button-submit">Submit</button>

    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - its a good piece of code - The browser still refreshes tho